# Number of sub sequences of length K having total sum S, given 2d array

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, substring

I wish to find *Number of sub sequences of length K having total sum S, given an array.*

**Sample Input:**

```
a=[1,1,1,2,2] & K=2 & S=2
```

**Sample Output:**

```
3 {because a[0],a[1]; a[1]a[2]; a[0]a[2] are only three possible for the case}
```

I have tried to write a **recursive loop** in **Python** for starter but it isn't giving output as expected.Please can you help me find a loophole I might be missing on.

```
def rec(k, sum1, arr, i=0):                                 
    #print('k: '+str(k)+' '+'sum1: '+str(sum1))     #(1) BaseCase: 
    if(sum1==0 and k!=0):                           #    Both sum(sum1) required and 
        return 0                                    #    numbers from which sum is required(k)
    if(k==0 and sum1 !=0):                          #    should be simultaneously zero
        return 0                                    #    Then required subsequences are 1
    if(k==0 and sum1==0 ):                          # 
        return 1                                    #
    base_check = sum1!=0 or k!=0                    #(2) if iterator i reaches final element 
    if(i==len(arr) and base_check):                 #    in array we should return 0 if both k 
        return 0                                    #    and sum1 aren't zero
                                                    #    func rec for getting sum1 from k elements 
    if(sum1<arr[0]):                                #    takes either first element or rejects it
        ans=rec(k-1,sum1,arr[i+1:len(arr)],i+1)     #    so 2 cases in else loop 
        print(ans)                                  #    i is taken in as iterator to provide array 
    else:                                           #    input to rec func from 2nd element of array 
        ans=rec(k-1, sum1-arr[0], arr[i+1:len(arr)],i+1)+rec(k, sum1, arr[i+1:len(arr)],i+1)
        #print('i: '+str(i)+' ans: '+str(ans))      
    return(ans)

a=[1,1,1,2,2]
print(rec(2,2,a))
```

I am still unable to process how to make changes. Once this normal recursive code is written I might go to **DP** approach accordinlgy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `itertools.combinations`

Function [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) returns all the subsequences of a given lengths. Then we filter to keep only subsequences who sum up to the desired value.

```py
import itertools
def countsubsum(a, k, s):
  return sum(1 for c in itertools.combinations(a,k) if sum(c)==s)
```

### Fixing your code

Your code looks pretty good, but there are two things that appear wrong about it.

**What is this `if` for?**

At first I was a bit confused about `if(sum1<arr[0]):`. I think you can (and should) always go to the else branch. After thinking about it some more, I understand you are trying to get rid of one of the two recursive calls if `arr[0]` is too large to be taken, which is smart, but this makes the assumption that all elements in the array are nonnegative. If the array is allowed to contain negative numbers, then you can include a large `a[0]` in the subsequence, and hope for a negative element to compensate. So if the array can contain negative numbers, you should get rid of this `if`/`else` and always execute the two recursive calls from the `else` branch.

**You are slicing wrong**

You maintain a variable `i` to remember where to start in the array; but you also slice the array. Pretty soon your indices become wrong. You should use slices, or use an index `i`, but not both.

```py
# WRONG
ans=rec(k-1, sum1-arr[0], arr[i+1:len(arr)],i+1)+rec(k, sum1, arr[i+1:len(arr)],i+1)

# CORRECT
ans = rec(k-1, sum1-arr[i], arr, i+1) + rec(k, sum1, arr, i+1)

# CORRECT
ans = rec(k-1, sum1-arr[0], arr[1:]) + rec(k, sum1, arr[1:])
```

To understand why using both slicing and an index gives wrong results, run the following code:

```py
def iter_array_wrong(a, i=0):
  if (a):
    print(i, a)
    iter_array_wrong(a[i:], i+1)

def iter_array_index(a, i=0):
  if i < len(a):
    print(i, a)
    iter_array_index(a, i+1)

def iter_array_slice(a):
  if a:
    print(a)
    iter_array_slice(a[1:])

print('WRONG')
iter_array_wrong(list(range(10)))
print()
print('INDEX')
iter_array_index(list(range(10)))
print()
print('SLICE')
iter_array_slice(list(range(10)))
```

Also note that `a[i:len(a)]` is exactly equivalent to `a[i:]` and `a[0:j]` is equivalent to `a[:j]`.

### Clean version of the recursion

Recursively count the subsequences who use the first element of the array, and the subsequences who don't use the first element of the array, and add the two counts. To avoid explicitly slicing the array repeatedly, which is an expensive operation, we keep a variable `start` to remember we are only working on subarray `a[start:]`.

```py
def countsubsum(a, k, s, start=0):
  if k == 0:
    return (1 if s == 0 else 0)
  elif start == len(a):
    return 0
  else:
    using_first_element = countsubsum(a, k-1, s-a[start], start+1)
    notusing_first_elem = countsubsum(a, k, s, start+1)
    return using_first_element + notusing_first_elem
```

Comment: This is really helping. Thanks a lot for the answer!!